# translating the Time text to another language

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, translation

How can i translate the default Cake php time helper strings in my application, i'm using in Cake php a function called `timeAgoInWords` which from the time helper function, it give me a text like `5 hours, 52 minutes ago` .

I want to translate this to another language, how can i do that ? i searched the documentation and i didn't get anything .

```
 <?php echo $this->Time->timeAgoInWords($question['Question']['created']) ?>
```

Comment: Not knowing any other information, I'd say the easiest way would be to simply replace the English words with the correct language words using str_replace.

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: yes i know the function, but how can i use that in cakephp

Comment: Er... what? Take the string you got from `timeAgoInWords`, and use `str_replace` on that string.  `str_replace` is a PHP function.  Right?

Comment: There's an official plugin for localizing certain portions of CakePHP.  See https://github.com/cakephp/localized  You're lookng for the section about LC_TIME  I also recommend reading more about localization - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html Pay particular attention to those parts that discuss LC_TIME.

Comment: From the docs it looks like `timeAgoInWords` is not localizable, in that case maybe it's better to make your own method `timeAgoInWords_XX` where XX is your language. Start off with cakephp's `timeAgoInWords` and then modify it to suit your language.

Comment: @Brandin It _is_ localizable, like pretty much anything in CakePHP. Not everything is documented in the CookBook though, a quick look at the sourcecode however reveals all the localizable messages.

Comment: @ndm For this kind of function localization strings are probably not enough. Consider the example in English "5 days ago". In German this would translate to "vor 5 Tagen". Similar problems will undoubtedly come up in many languages for some of these time messages.

Comment: For what you are asking... You need a custom helper...

Comment: I have posted an answer that you can use - Hmm, gives a thought of integrating this script with timeAgoInWords helper to help replace words like ago, hours, minutes, seconds, days, etc.

Comment: @Brandin Why should that be a problem? The messages for that are `%s ago` and `%d days`, in german that would be `vor %s` and `%d Tagen`, which would finally end up as `vor 5 Tagen`. I've localized `CakeTime` for various languages and never had a problem, however I can't speak for all languages of course.

Comment: @ndm I have no idea why that would be a problem. I'm guilty of responding to these comments without even having bothered to look at the code for this function. If it's that way though then that sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

You need a customized helper to get your stuff done. timeAgoInWords helper does not give the flexiblity of replacing words with your words.

Here, create a file called **TimeagoHelper.php** under your `View/Helper`

I am not sure which language you want translation in, I will write in English, you can replace your words.

```
<?php

App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');


class TimeagoHelper extends AppHelper {

    public function __construct(View $view, $settings = array()) {
        parent::__construct($view, $settings);
    }


    public function timeago($datetime) {
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($datetime);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime('now');
        $obj = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        if($obj->days == 1) {
            $time = $obj->format('%a day'); // Replace your word
        } elseif($obj->days == 0) {
            if($obj->h == 0) {
                if($obj->i == 0) {
                    $time = $obj->s . ' seconds'; // Replace your word
                } else {
                    $time = $obj->i . ' minutes'; // Replace your word
                }
            } else {
                $time = $obj->h . ' hours'; // Replace your word
            }
        } else {
            $time = $obj->format('%a days'); // Replace your word
        }
        return $time.' ago'; // Replace your word
    }
}
```

Load this helper in your action or controller.

I have been using php 5.5 since quite sometime, am not sure if it works on lesser versions, i.e. don't remember if concat is allowed as done for seconds and minutes. Incase, it doesn't work, assign them to variables and concat those.

Use it in View's `.ctp` file like so:

`$this->Timeago->timeago($question['Question']['created']);`

PS: CakeTime comes in handy too, check out the [api](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeTime.html) for possibilities.

Cheers!

Comment: Please note: This is not how a standard helper should look like. This is only to get your work done with least possible iterations. More flexibility by implementing localization - which would be more standard approach.

Comment: There is no need for a custom helper, all that is needed is localization for `CakeTime`!

Comment: Hey, that's fantastic! I didn't knew about `CakeTime`! +1 for your comment. I will edit my answer. However, this custom helper isn't bad either... I wrote a quick hack to get stuff done! That's all :) Also, please check my 1st comment, I did mention that it is not how a standard helper should be, just a quick hack for OP.